# Accessing request.user in class based generic view CreateView in order to set FK field in Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views, django-class-based-views

So I have a model that includes:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    ....
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

My view is like so:

```
class PlaceFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = PlaceForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlaceFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way for me to access request.user and set created_by to that user?  I've looked through the docs, but can't seem to find any hints toward this.

`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How about overriding `form_valid` which does the form saving? Save it yourself, do whatever you want to it, then do the redirect.

```
class PlaceFormView(CreateView):
    form_class = PlaceForm

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlaceFormView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.created_by = self.request.user
        obj.save()        
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, except for the redirect.  I get the error: "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model." However, I do have a get_absolute_url() set on the model, and when I first got this view working (with created_by a select box on form) it redirected properly.  Trying to figure this out now.  Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, it appears get_absolute_url is pulled from self.object - so in your code, set `self.object = obj` in `form_valid`

Comment: Is it possible to do this without extending the CreateView?

Comment: Shouldn't we rather do at the end of form_valid:
    return super(PlaceFormView, self).form_valid(form)
Otherwise the default form_valid is never called...

Comment: @Marc the "default" form_valid does the same, you can check it easily at ccbv.co.uk, it justs saves the object and redirects.

Comment: Awsome answer. Works like a charm !

Answer (score 25):

I know that this is old, but for other people with this problem:

There is an even simpler way - since saving a form multiple times will always use the same model instance, you can also do:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.created_by = self.request.user
    return super(PlaceFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

That way, you get all the benefits of the super call - it's trivial to see that you're really only adding those two lines of code, and you don't have to repeat yourself by replicating the redirect logic.

Answer (score 6):

An alternate way to do this is to pass the user through overwriting the get_initial() method in the CreateView, and modify save method in the PlaceForm class to save the user:

```
class PlaceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    ...
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_by = kwargs['initial']['created_by']
        super(PlaceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        obj = super(PlaceForm, self).save(False)
        obj.created_by = self.created_by
        commit and obj.save()
        return obj

class PlaceFormView(CreateView):
    ...
    ...
    form_class = PlaceForm

    def get_initial(self):
        self.initial.update({ 'created_by': self.request.user })
        return self.initial
```

This way the saving logic is still encapsulated within the form class.

Comment: This worked for me and seems like the best and simplest way to solve this problem