# Automatically link a User to another model when saving?

Tags: django

I have a model with a ForeignKey to User, and it needs to have a value. How do I automatically add the User value when submitting a form?

The model doesn't seem to have access to the request object, so I can't do it at it's `save()` method.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Similar question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785727/accessing-request-user-in-class-based-generic-view-createview-in-order-to-set-fk/7376147#7376147

Answer (score 1):

When submitting your form, you want to run `commit=False` on it so that it returns you an object without actually saving it. You can then assign the user to it. Here's an example:

```
profile = form.save(commit=False)
profile.user = request.user
profile.save()
```

Here's a little blurb on it in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: I'm using the CreateView generic view, is it possible to do it without extending it?

Comment: I haven't used generic views so unfortunately I can't help you there.