# Foreign key defaults to Auth User in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.11

I'm using `Django 1.11`

I have a business model.

```
class Business(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_type = models.ForeignKey(BusinessType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'business'
        verbose_name_plural = 'businesses'
        db_table = 'businesses'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I run `python3 manage.py makemigration business` It gives

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'user' to business without a default;
```

I want to set this field to use the logged in user id as foreign key by default.

**How to use Auth user id as default for user specific data record?**

> Edit 2

**Business create view** `views.py`

```
class BusinessCreate(CreateView):
    model = Business
    fields = ['name', 'business_type']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(
            BusinessCreate,
            self
        ).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        if self.request.POST:
            data['business_address'] = BusinessAddressFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['business_address'] = BusinessAddressFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        business_address = context['business_address']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if business_address.is_valid():
                business_address.instance = self.object
                business_address.save()

        return super(BusinessCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Business Added Successfully')
        return reverse('business:list')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the default user in case of ForeignKey coz that field is `non nullable`.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

**Update After Comment**

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(BusinessCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: if user with pk=1 is not exists?

Comment: I want to set default to user id who is logged in

Comment: You can not do that, for that you need request variable which can be accessed in model.

Comment: @AnujTBE, Feel privileged to help you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that. The current user only makes sense in the context of a http request. Migrations cannot rely on that context. You must instead pass the current user explicitly when creating new `Business` instances in a view function.

Comment: I have updated question with create view. How to pass explicitly?

Comment: You can override `form_valid` and add the current user to the form. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34239078/1977847