# How to associate model with current user while saving in django

Tags: django

I'm new to django so sorry for this simple question. I'm building web app using django. and i want to save current logged in user while he/she create any new object automatically. I want to implement this features in custom admin panel.

```
class Post(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeginKey(...)
   .............
```

So here i want to fill user field automatically.

Comment: how are you saving the post object?

Comment: @NalinDobhal using generic create view

Comment: You can access the `request.user` in the `form_valid` method [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785727](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785727/accessing-request-user-in-class-based-generic-view-createview-in-order-to-set-fk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the user model directly.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeginKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Or you can use the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting (this is recommended)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeginKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Inside your generic create view you can then associate the `request.user` with the object inside the `form_valid` method as explained here [Accessing request.user in class based generic view CreateView in order to set FK field in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785727/accessing-request-user-in-class-based-generic-view-createview-in-order-to-set-fk)

```
class PostView(CreateView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()        
        return http.HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```